# Dependency Injection loses type safety with struct arguments

Tags: go, dependency-injection, dry, circular-dependency

A common pattern in Go is to use *dependency injection* as a means to get around *circular imports*.

For example, [here is a very short code snippet](https://play.golang.org/p/NRPXgoOeIyC) defining two objects, `House` and `Garage`. A `Dispatcher` abstraction is used so that they can call each others methods at will. (The `Dispatcher` is *injected* into each object.)

So far, so good.

Building on this code snippet, imagine that I code a new method of `House` that takes 10 arguments:

```golang
type HouseDispatcher interface {
    // This matches all of the methods of house.House
    SetThermostat(temp int)
    PrepareBedroom(arg1 int, arg2 int64, arg3 int32, arg4 uint64, arg5 uint32, arg6 string, arg7 rune, arg8 int, arg9 int, arg10 int)
}
```

This code smells, so we need to refactor it into an object:

```golang
type BedroomData struct {
    arg1 int
    arg2 int64
    arg3 int32
    arg4 uint64
    arg5 uint32
    arg6 string
    arg7 rune
    arg8 int
    arg9 int
    arg10 int
}

type HouseDispatcher interface {
    // This matches all of the methods of house.House
    SetThermostat(temp int)
    PrepareBedroom(data BedroomData)
}
```

Much better! But it makes sense for the `BedroomData` struct to live in the `House.go` file, next to all of the other code relating to Houses.

So when we scaffold the method in the Dispatcher, we are forced to code it as such:

```golang
type HouseDispatcher interface {
    // This matches all of the methods of house.House
    SetThermostat(temp int)
    PrepareBedroom(data interface{})
}
```

And now we have lost type safety.

We can gain back type safety by duplicating the `BedroomData` struct definition in the `Dispatcher`, but now we have violated DRY - the two structs could become out of sync and lead to disastrous runtime errors.

So what is the solution?

Comment: Put the struct into a `model` package, and define both the interface and the implementation using that.

Comment: That's smart and should solve the problem. Although, it is annoying not having all house-related data in the house package. Is there a better solution?

Comment: There's the obvious one: put `House` and `Garage` into the same package. However, the idea of putting interfaces and models into a separate package than the implementation is  a common pattern.

Comment: While I can follow your example, it seems forced, and unrealistic. I've never seen code like this. Do you have a real-world example where this problem is biting you?

Answer (score 1):

Why does the Garage tell the House to prepare a BedRoom? That function should never be in the interface given to the Garage **if** the Garage never calls it. Define the House interface in the Garage package with only the functions needed in the Garage package and have another interface (if needed at all and you can't just use the struct itself) for general usage of the House type.

`// This matches all of the methods of house.House` <- This is the problem right here. Interfaces that have all the functions of a type are "weak". They don't really help much apart from being able to declare them in another package and solve a circular reference that way.

Let me give an example on how this could be structured:

Package garage:

```golang
type House interface {
    // Put only function here that the Garage package needs
    SetThermostat(temp int)
}

// imagining things from here on:

func NewGarage(house House) *Garage {
    return &Garage{
        house: House,
    }
}

type Garage struct {
    house House
}

func (s *Garage) HeatHouse(temp int) {
    // use house here
    s.house.SetThermostat(temp)
}
```

Package House:

```golang
type Garage interface {
    // Put only functions here the House package needs from Garage
}

type House struct {
    // ...
}

type BedroomData struct {
    arg1 int
    arg2 int64
    arg3 int32
    arg4 uint64
    arg5 uint32
    arg6 string
    arg7 rune
    arg8 int
    arg9 int
    arg10 int
}

func (s *House) PrepareBedroom(data BedroomData) {
    // ...
}
```

---

This is not an absolute rule but helps in many cases: Define an interface for the ***use case***. (In contrast to defining the interface for an entire type)

Answer (score 0):

This example may be too contrived to demonstrate what you're talking about. In general, I prefer to have a root package that defines the shared data model and services. The packages provide the services and act on the model. The packages can also define and use any types they need internally, which no other package should need. If you're injecting a dependency, that dependency should be a shared service interface, and if you're passing data, it should be from the shared model. Packages should only ever communicate with each other using the shared model.

In your example, `BedroomData` would be part of the shared model. It's not a dependency, it's data, so it doesn't need to be passed in with an interface; there's never a reason to need a separate implementation of something that only holds data. If it's not really part of the shared model, then it shouldn't be getting passed in from outside.